# Time complexity of using heaps to find Kth largest element

Tags: c++, search, heap

I have some different implementations of the code for finding the Kth largest element in an unsorted array. The three implementations I use all use either min/max heap, but I am having trouble figuring out the runtime complexity for one of them.

Implementation 1:

```
int findKthLargest(vector<int> vec, int k)
{
    // build min-heap
    make_heap(vec.begin(), vec.end(), greater<int>());

    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        vec.pop_back();
    }

    return vec.back();
}
```

Implementation 2:

```
int findKthLargest(vector<int> vec, int k)
{
    // build max-heap
    make_heap(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        // move max. elem to back (from front)
        pop_heap(vec.begin(), vec.end()); 
        vec.pop_back();
    }

    return vec.front();
}
```

Implementation 3:

```
int findKthLargest(vector<int> vec, int k)
{
    // max-heap prio. q
    priority_queue<int> pq(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        pq.pop();
    }

    return pq.top();
}
```

From my reading, I am under the assumption that the runtime for the SECOND one is O(n) + O(klogn) = O(n + klogn). This is because building the max-heap is done in O(n) and popping it will take O(logn)*k if we do so 'k' times.

However, here is where I am getting confused. For the FIRST one, with a min-heap, I assume building the heap is O(n). Since it is a min-heap, larger elements are in the back. Then, popping the back element 'k' times will cost k*O(1) = O(k). Hence, the complexity is O(n + k).

And similarly, for the third one, I assume the complexity is also O(n + klogn) with the same reasoning I had for the max-heap.

But, some sources still say that this problem cannot be done faster than O(n + klogn) with heaps/pqs! In my FIRST example, I think this complexity is O(n + k), however. Correct me if I'm wrong. Need help thx.

Comment: Your first approach use O(n) time to produce the wrong solution: the heap doesn’t have the largest (or smallest depending on the predicate) elements at end. Its internal structure means that the root of each [sub]tree is the smallest (largest) element in this [sub]tree. This structure provides efficient access to the smallest (largest) element and efficient update methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly implemented, getting the kth largest element from a min-heap is O((n-k) * log(n)). Getting the kth largest element from a max-heap is O(k * log(n)).

Your first implementation is not at all correct. For example, if you wanted to get the largest element from the heap (k == 1), the loop body would never be executed. Your code assumes that the last element in the vector is the largest element on the heap. That is incorrect. For example, consider the heap:

```
 1
3 2
```

That is a perfectly valid heap, which would be represented by the vector `[1,3,2]`. Your first implementation would not work to get the 1st or 2nd largest element from that heap.

The second solution looks like it would work.

Your first two solutions end up removing items from `vec`. Is that what you intended?

The third solution is correct. It takes O(n) to build the heap, and O((k - 1) log n) to remove the (k-1) largest items. And then O(1) to access the largest remaining item.

There *is* another way to do it, that is potentially faster in practice. The idea is:

```
build a min-heap of size k from the first k elements in vec
for each following element
    if the element is larger than the smallest element on the heap
        remove the smallest element from the heap
        add the new element to the heap
return element at the top of the heap
```

This is O(k) to build the initial heap. Then it's O((n-k) log k) *in the worst case* for the remaining items. The worst case occurs when the initial vector is in ascending order. That doesn't happen very often. In practice, a small percentage of items are added to the heap, so you don't have to do all those removals and insertions.

Some heap implementations have a `heap_replace` method that combines the two steps of removing the top element and adding the new element. That reduces the complexity by a constant factor. (i.e. rather than an O(log k) removal followed by an O(log k) insertion, you get an constant time replacement of the top element, followed by an O(log k) sifting it down the heap).

Comment: Thanks Jim! Solidified my fundamental understanding of the heap data structure. Building a heap does not necessarily sort an array in an order but rather makes it so that the elements satisfy the heap property. Hence, implementation 1 would not work. Also thanks for the pseudocode for the min-heap approach! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is heap solution for java. We remove all elements which are less than kth element from the min heap. After that we will have kth largest element at the top of the min heap.

```
class Solution {
    int kLargest(int[] arr, int k) {
        
        PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b)-> Integer.compare(a, b));
        for(int a : arr) {
            heap.add(a);
            if(heap.size()>k) {
                // remove smallest element in the heap
                heap.poll();
            }
        }
        // return kth largest element
        return heap.poll();
    }
}
```

The worst case time complexity will be O(N*logK) where N is total no of elements. You will be using 1 heapify operation when inserting initial k elements in heap. After that you'll be using 2 operations(1 insert and 1 remove). So this makes the worst case time complexity O(N*logK). You can improve it with some other methods and bring the average case time complexity of heap update to Θ(1). Read [this](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Ehayward/papers/heap.pdf) for more info.

---

#### Quickselect: Θ(N)

If you're looking for a faster solution on average. Quickselect algorithm which is based on quick sort is a good option. It provides average case time complexity of O(N) and O(1) space complexity. Of course worst case time complexity is O(N^2) however randomized pivot(used in following code) yields very low probability for such scenario. Following is code for quickselect algo for finding kth largest element.

```
class Solution {
    public int findKthLargest(int[] nums, int k) {
        return quickselect(nums, k);
    }
     
    private int quickselect(int[] nums, int k) {
        int n = nums.length;
        int start = 0, end = n-1;
        while(start<end) {
            int ind = partition(nums, start, end);
            if(ind == n-k) {
                return nums[ind];
            } else if(ind < n-k) {
                start = ind+1;
            } else {
                end = ind-1;
            }
        }
        return nums[start];
    }
    
    private int partition(int[] nums, int start, int end) {
        int pivot = start + (int)(Math.random()*(end-start));
        swap(nums, pivot, end);
        
        int left=start;
        for(int curr=start; curr<end; curr++) {
            if(nums[curr]<nums[end]) {
                swap(nums, left, curr);
                left++;
            }
        }
        swap(nums, left, end);
        return left;
    }
    
    private void swap(int[] nums, int i, int j) {
        int temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = temp;
    }
}
```